# Confusing button focus when using multiple NG Bootstrap datepickers

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using Angular 8 with [NG Bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap).

When I have multiple NG Bootstrap datepickers in a single form and click between the datepicker buttons without selecting any dates the button focus seems to jump to the previously clicked datepicker button (StackBlitz  [editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x8armu?file=app%2Fdatepicker-popup.html) and [app](https://angular-x8armu.stackblitz.io)).

This isn't a big issue, but is there a way to prevent this?

My code:

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="a" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker">
<button (click)="d1.toggle()" type="button">Datepicker</button>

<input [(ngModel)]="b" ngbDatepicker #d2="ngbDatepicker">
<button (click)="d2.toggle()" type="button">Datepicker</button>

<input [(ngModel)]="c" ngbDatepicker #d3="ngbDatepicker">
<button (click)="d3.toggle()" type="button">Datepicker</button>
```

Comment: Can you please include some piece of your code to the question? And it would be great if you link stackblitz in edit mode

Comment: @yurzui I changed the link to the editor and the specific file (for some reason the app doesn't load in the sidebar anymore and only works with "Open in New Window" now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this [bug reported](http://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pull/3530/files) and there is [the pr](http://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/pull/3530/files) to fix it